# Excel VBA RemoveDuplicates function with case sensitivity

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove some duplicates from selected column, but the function removes all duplicates irrespective of the case. `RemoveDuplicates` considers lower case, upper case, etc as duplicate. E.g. the function removed `CENTRAL`, `central` and `Central`.

I have simply recorded the following code and only changed it a little bit. I need to keep items with different cases and don't want to remove as duplicates.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A:A").Clear
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    'Range("B12").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A:A").Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code using a `Dictionary` to remove duplicates with case sensitivity:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    RemoveDuplicates Sheet1.Range("A1:A12")
End Sub

Sub RemoveDuplicates(rngDataColumn As Range)
'assumes rngDataColumn is a column of data

    Dim dic As Object
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim varKey As Variant
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    'create dictionary
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'dictionary becomes case sensitive
    dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare

    'iterate range for unique values
    For Each rngCell In rngDataColumn
        If Not dic.Exists(rngCell.Value) Then
            dic.Add Key:=rngCell.Value, Item:=True
        End If
    Next rngCell

    'clear source range
    rngDataColumn.ClearContents

    'output unique items - with case sensitivity
    lngCounter = 1
    For Each varKey In dic.Keys
        rngDataColumn(lngCounter, 1).Value = varKey
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    Next varKey

End Sub
```

A1:A12 in my test case is as follows:

[image]

So, to update your recorded macro, you could try:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A:A").Clear
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'use the new function here
    RemoveDuplicates Selection
    'Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    'Range("B12").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A:A").Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/577181-case-sensitive-removal-duplicates-visual-basic-applications.html) and tested some nice solution, that seems to meet your expectations. You have to paste this function into your project:

```
Option Compare Binary
Sub deleteExactDuplicates(ByVal rng As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each i In rng.Cells
            v = i.Value
            If .exists(v) Then
                i.ClearContents
            Else
                .Add v, 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Then, you have to call it in your code. If I understand, you want to remove duplicates from selected range, so the macro would look like this:

```
Sub test()
   deleteExactDuplicates Selection
End Sub
```

Now, this solution delete not only the values in selected range, but also entire rows, where duplicated values occurred. Are you OK with that, or you need something that removes duplicates only from particular range?